# Can I combine two inputs into one?

Tags: solenoid, powermosfet

I have a device (schematic drawn by me) with two separate solenoid drive circuits.

[image]

I need two inputs for one solenoid. Can I simply combine the inputs through diodes like this? The inputs are digital 5 V and Vcc is 24 V.

[image]

Comment: And just an FYI, what you have come up with is an architecture (diode-oring) that is commonly used to provide redundancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that configuration should work.  It's called "diode OR-ing".

Comment: OP has to make sure the diodes voltage drop don't put him/her outside the recommended input voltage for U3 (no, i did not look at the data sheet).